# Setting a url pattern for all new instances of a specific page type in Kentico?

Tags: url-rewriting, kentico

I've got a custom page type (olliEvent) that end users use to make new events in our Kentico 9 CMS. Because of the way our site is built, the url path that would be generated from the site tree would be incorrect. I need to automatically set a custom url path each time the end user creates a new olliEvent page. These pages have exclusive use of the olliEvent page type and a olliEvent page template, so we can set parameters on those if we need to.

The file tree is:
/subsites/olli/class-listing/(pageName)

I'd like for the url to be:
/olli/class-listing/(pageName)

I can think of two ways to approach this:

1) Exclude the "subsites" folder when creating urls based on the file tree. Is there a way to do this?

2) Make some sort of macro type url that is set at the page type or page template level. Is this possible?

Thanks!
Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do that is to create a Event Handler for this page type, so when this page type page is created/updated, the event handler will set the URL path/pattern to /olli/class-listing/(pageName)

https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/handling-global-events

Comment: Thanks, Rui. This is the approach we are going to take.